# 301 Redirect with url parameters?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parameters, http-status-code-301

I'm reworking a site for a client and they have old search items I want to redirect for now.  I've been successful up until urls that had parameters.  I've tried to find a solution but now I'm at a loss.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} f=products&product=163$
RewriteRule (.*) /lighting-breath-cocoon/? [R=301,L]
```

That's an example of what I've tried and for some reason it wont work, I don't quite understand why.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Try [R=301,QSA,L]

Comment: You might need to drop the ? char from the rewrite url for QSA to work. If that doesn't still work, you could also try:
RewriteRule . /lighting-breath-cocoon/?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L] . And of course do check the doc: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString